# Sort Solr documents based on a substring from a multivalued field

Tags: search, solr, lucene, solrj

Not sure if I can achieve this

I have the below documents in the index

```
{
  "name": "nissan",
  "type": "product",
  "features":["build_100",
          "stability_80"]
}

{
  "name": "toyota",
  "type": "product",
  "features":["stability_100",
          "design_30"]
}

{
  "name": "Audi",
  "type": "product",
 "features":["build_70",
          "design_100"]
}
```

For a search of build in the features field "design" I get doc 2 and 3 back from recall and my question is that is there a way I could sort/rank the documents based on the number after the "_", so that in the above case I would get doc3 first and then doc 2?

If this can be achieved by changing the document structure then that is also fine with me.

Answer (score 1):

Index them as independent fields and make sure to enable docValues on them (enabled by default on recent version of Solr).

```
<dynamicField name="features_*" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

You then index each feature as a separate field:

```
"feature_design": 100,
"feature_build": 70,
```

and so on. Sorting by the field can then be done in the same was you'd sort on any other field (`sort=feature_design`).